# Is it okay to use HTML and CSS instead of ionic UI elements?

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic and I'm asking myself if there is any differences between ionic UI components and HTML components while developing for IOS and Android devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is "OK" but yes there are differences. The ionic framework has many hooks into style sheets and compile time translations. [Consider this discussion in the Ionic forum.](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-vs-div-directives/7524)